# Making a 0 by 0 pixels SurfaceView - how?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to use MediaRecorder without showing the user a preview of the video being captured.
As far as I understand that can be achieved by making a SurfaceView of 0 by 0 pixels.hank
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i remember it has to be 1 by 1 pixels and 0 pixels will not work because the framework would consider it as not visible

Comment: Yes but how do you do that exactly?

Comment: in your XML create a videoView and make it width and height of 1 dp.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it invisible?

You can do it programatically:

yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);